# Alexa Lambda KeyError: 'intent'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I don't know a lot about programming but have been working with raspberry Pi for a few years. I wanted to use Alexa in the Pi and run scripts to turn on and off the GPIOS. After trying some tutorials I got to the point where I connected AWS Lambda with the Alexa skill. The problem is that I get an error when testing the skill.
"Skill response was marked as failure
Luces
Request Identifier: amzn1.echo-api.request.49687858-4c4f-482f-b82d-dd0ffedc9841

The target Lambda application returned a failure response"

I check the log on the AWS cloud and this is what I got.

```
'intent': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 40, in lambda_handler
    intent_name = event['request']['intent']['name']
KeyError: 'intent
```

I don't have a clue of what to do. I adapted the code from a hackster.io tutorial. My Lambda code with python 2.7 is:

```
import boto3

access_key = 
access_secret = 
region =
queue_url = 

def build_speechlet_response(title, output, reprompt_text, should_end_session):
    return {
        'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'PlainText',
            'text': output
        },
        'card': {
            'type': 'Simple',
            'title': "SessionSpeechlet - " + title,
            'content': "SessionSpeechlet - " + output
        },
        'reprompt': {
            'outputSpeech': {
                'type': 'PlainText',
                'text': reprompt_text
            }
        },
        'shouldEndSession': should_end_session
    }

def build_response(session_attributes, speechlet_response):
    return {
        'version': '1.0',
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'response': speechlet_response
    }

def post_message(client, message_body, url):
    response = client.send_message(QueueUrl = url, MessageBody= message_body)
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('sqs', aws_access_key_id = access_key, aws_secret_access_key = access_secret, region_name = region)
    intent_name = event['request']['intent']['name']
    if intent_name == "LightOn":
        post_message(client, 'on', queue_url)
        message = "on"
    elif intent_name == "LightOff":
        post_message(client, 'off', queue_url)
        message = "off"
    else:
        message = "Unknown"
        
    speechlet = build_speechlet_response("Mirror Status", message, "", "true")
    return build_response({}, speechlet)
```

I just want to turn the led on and then off but I don't know if I need all that code. If there is a simple way to code this in lamba please tell me.

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several different request types, the "standard ones" being: `CanFulfillIntentRequest`, `LaunchRequest`, `IntentRequest`, and `SessionEndedRequest`.

You first open the skill, it'll be a `LaunchRequest` that's sent - which does not contain the `intent` parameter. That's likely why you're getting the `KeyError`.

A good approach is to check the request type before you try to process it.

```
if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
    print("I'm a launch request.")
elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
    print("I'm an intent request.")
```

The various request types and the parameters they can hold can be found in the [Alexa documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html).

Comment: So, `LaunchRequest` its like declaring a variable? So I need to start with 
`import boto3

LaunchRequest == intent` ?

Comment: Ok! I managed to do what you recommended. It printed "I'm a launch request." and got the same error with the request. So, I need to change that to an "Intent request"?

Comment: @PablinhoRiveiro If you're struggling to get your head around how Alexa skills work and how they interact with lambda functions - a good idea is probably to take a look at the [Alexa GitHub page](https://amazon.com/alexa) where there are plenty of examples of basic skill functionality that's helpful when starting out.